# Что такое Aktenplan?

Tags: терминология

Часто вижу на работе но не знаю что это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, это архивный термин, который используется в автоматизированных системах для упорядоченного хранения файлов и папок.

Comment: Немного поискав пришел к тому же выводу.

Answer (score 3):

Это явно немецкий термин. Поэтому ползем на [германскую Wiki](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktenplan) и пытаемся понять. Если сложно напрямую - пользуемся [переводчиком](http://translate.google.ru/).

Если попытаться объяснить своими словами - это способ организации документооборота путем придумывания названий документам по определенной системе.

Comment: Да с немецкого переводится как "файл план",уже понял для чего она мне нужна.